# Scrape the hidden input's value by using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to scrape with beautiful soup yellow highlighted value "entry.1661051188" but I can access it somehow. With hidden_tags I can't access it. Maybe someone has an Idea how I could access it with...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import random





source = requests.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfRS67JXAG8XXeeXM5Yz7-vA5Lp7-IKuiCHNANR0WLWo-qCxw/viewform")
src = source.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,"html.parser")
s =  requests.Session()

hidden_tags = soup.find("input")


print(hidden_tags)
```

[image: html code]

Answer (score 0):

For getting the hidden input tag you can use `type`. Like this way

```
hidden_tags = soup.find_all('input', {'type':'hidden'})
```

but why you used this

```
src = source.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,"html.parser")
s =  requests.Session()
```

creating `session` after calling the url is not required if you want to use session then do it before calling the url and then use it as,

```
session = req.session()

src = session.get(URL)
```

if you want to persist the cookies and headers and want to make multiple calls then only use session.
And creating extra variable  `src = source.content` just to hold source is not optimal try to use it directly inside parser

Comment: hey thanks for your help, but with hidden_tags = soup.find_all('input', {'type':'hidden'}) it  doesnt work either. I already tried it before doing this post. If you want you can check yourself https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSfRS67JXAG8XXeeXM5Yz7-vA5Lp7-IKuiCHNANR0WLWo-qCxw/formResponse

Comment: Then it must be a dynamic page try selenium